# Is there any error in my httpd.conf?

Tags: apache

Here is my httpd.conf

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName m.testaaaa.com
    # ServerAlias m.testaaaa.org
    ServerAdmin admin@testaaaa.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/testaaaa.err
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/testaaaa.log combined
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/m.testaaaa.com
    <Directory "/var/www/html/m.testaaaa.com">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>

   <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName testaaaa.com
    ServerAlias www.testaaaa.org
    ServerAdmin admin@testaaaa.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/testaaaa.err
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/testaaaa.log combined
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/testaaaa.com
    <Directory "/var/www/html/testaaaa.com">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

It works but why when I open http://192.168.0.110/ (the server ip) in browser, httpd shows the same webpage as http://m.testaaaa.com?

I think using 192.168.0.110 shouldn't open http://m.testaaaa.com
because the serverName isn't m.testaaaa.com.

Is there any error in my httpd.conf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

Its redirection all unmatched request to DocumentRoot /var/www/html/m.testaaaa.com

you must use a document root only for *:80

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/unmatched"
</VirtualHost>
```

And then setup every domain:

```
<VirtualHost domain1:80>
    ServerName domain1
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/domain1"
</VirtualHost>
```

In this way your if you access with your IP will get the files listed in the unmatched folder

Answer (score 1):

It's not an error.

By default Apache serves the very first virtualhost for requests to any unmatched host names.

You can add a new virtualhost **above** `m.testaaaa.com` and it will work when you address by IP.